# RestKit .20.x value transformation

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am new to iOS development and am trying to do some custom value transformation in RestKit, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I have two current problems:

1. I have a base64 encoded image that is returning in a JSON message from the server.  It is in the below format.  I am using Core Data as the backend persistent store and the 'image' field is stored in Core Data as binary data (NSData).  When RestKit transforms the base64 encoded image into an NSData object, something goes wrong because the image bytes that are stored in the sqllite database are not correct and I can't redisplay the image.

   ```
   "images": [{
    "id": 1,
    "recordId": 1,
    "status": "C",
    "type": "MUGSHOT",
    "format": "JPEG",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
    "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAA....",
    "createBy": "blah",
    "createDt": 1395683191483,
    "captureDevice": null
   }]
   ```
2. The createBy date is in ms since epoch, which isn't being transformed correctly into a NSDate object.  I understand that it is expecting the value to be in seconds, which I assume what is causing the problem.

After much googling, I found that RKValueTransformer will allow me to set up custom transformations for different classes (in my case, I'd want to set up a custom transformer for NSDate and NSData classes.  However, the RKBlockValueTransformer class that is referenced here (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping) under the "Customizing Value Transformation" section doesn't appear to exist for me.  I am using RestKit .20.3 and used CocoaPods to install it with this Podfile:

```
    platform :ios, '7.0'
    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.3'
```

I tried adding pod 'RKValueTransformers', '~> 1.0.0' to my Podfile, but that caused some compiler issues.  Plus, isn't the [RKValueTransformers project](https://github.com/RestKit/RKValueTransformers) just an extract of the value transformation feature already built into RestKit?

Am I on the right path with using the RKValueTransformer to get the NSDate and NSData behavior I am looking for?  If so, what do I have to do to get it included in my project?  Are there any easier ways to get my application to correctly handle base64 encoded images stored in Core Data as a binary field?

EDIT: Here is my RKValueTransformers.h and .m file in my Pods project.  It appears to be only date formatter related: [image: RKValueTransformers]

Comment: Are you getting any error when trying to create an image out of stored `NSData`?

Comment: No error, but when I pass the NSData into [UIImage imageWithData:] the returned UIImage is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing image data in Core Data you should think about ticking the 'allow external storage' option.

The value transformer you want is to convert `NSString` to `NSData` and you need to base64 in the middle. You need to create a class which conforms to `< RKValueTransforming >`. Because you are transforming from `NSString` you should implement `validateTransformationFromClass:toClass:` so you can reject any transformation where the destination isn't `NSData` efficiently.

Once you have created your class and in instance of it (`imageFormatter`), install it with:

```
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:imageFormatter atIndex:0];
```

and the same process applies for the date formatter.

Comment: For some reason, I don't have the RKValueTransforming protocol or RKValueTransformer class in my workspace.  The Podfile I used to install RestKit is pasted above.  Am I missing some other add on or something?

Comment: I don't actually use pods, do you see the RestKit project included in your project? Did you install all of the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, it is included in my project and Cocoapods also installed ASNetworking and other dependent projects (see screenshot above).  What .h file contains the RKValueTransforming class for you?  The download of RestKit .20.3 file also doesn't include the prototype or class you mentioned previously in the RKValueTransformers.h file.

Comment: RKValueTransformers.h, line 26. I'm using the development branch version 0.21.0. Master is at 0.22.0. 0.20.3 is 9 months old... You need to update

Comment: Yup, that was definitely the problem.  restkit.org says that the latest version is .20.3, which I put into my Podfile since I figured that was the latest version (silly me for assuming that they'll update their site?).  I changed around my Podfile to use .22, which downloaded the latest version with the right RKValueTransformer!  Thanks a lot for you help, I'm sure I'll be on the right track now!

Comment: You can also set the formatter on every RKPropertyMapping instance which maps a base64 key value pair to NSData.